# Getting wrong sum and count in linq

Tags: c#, linq

This is my table structure

```
ID   A     B     C     D

1    null  10    5     null
2    3     5     null  D2
3    8     null  2     D2
4    null  4     3     D1
5    4     6     1     D2
```

This is c# class and its property to store query result.

```
public class GrillTotals
{
        public int? SumOfA {get; set;}

        public int? SumOfB{get; set;}

        public int? SumOfC{get; set;}

        public int? CountOfD1{get; set;}

        public int? CountOfD2{get; set;}
}
```

What I expect is:

```
SumOfA = 15
SumOfB = 20
SumOfC = 11
CountOfD1 = 1
CountOfD2 = 3
```

What I am getting is :
    SumOfA = null, 
    SumOfB = null, 
    SumOfC = null, 
    CountOfD1 = 0, 
    CountOfD2 = 0

Here is a code what I have tried.

```
var _FinalResult = from s in dbContext.tblSchedules
 group s by new
 {
     s.A,
     s.B,
     s.C,
     s.D,
 } into gt
 select new GrillTotals
 {
     SumOfA = gt.Sum(g => g.A),
     SumOfB = gt.Sum(g => g.B),
     SumOfC = gt.Sum(g => g.C),
     CountOfD1 = gt.Count(g => g.D == "D1"),
     CountOfD2 = gt.Count(g => g.D == "D2"),
 };
```

Try to correct me if I am doing something wrong or incorrectly.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 10+5+4+6 is 20?

Comment: Use the ?? operator.

Comment: where I can use ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be grouping by the fields you want to calculate aggregates. When you group by them, every aggregate (Sum, Min, Max etc) will return the value itself (and Count 1 or 0 depending of the condition).

From what I see you are trying to return several aggregates with single SQL query. If that's correct, it's possible by using **group by constant** technique.

Just replace

```
 group s by new
 {
     s.A,
     s.B,
     s.C,
     s.D,
 } into gt
```

with

```
group s by 1 // any constant
into gt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var _FinalResult = from s in dbContext.tblSchedules
 group s by new
 {
     s.A,
     s.B,
     s.C,
     s.D,
 } into gt
 select new GrillTotals
 {
     SumOfA = gt.Sum(g => g.A ?? 0),
     SumOfB = gt.Sum(g => g.B ?? 0),
     SumOfC = gt.Sum(g => g.C ?? 0),
     CountOfD1 = gt.Count(g => g.D == "D1"),
     CountOfD2 = gt.Count(g => g.D == "D2"),
 };
```